# Hyper-V PLINQ Virtual Machine Parallel issue

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, virtual-machine, hyper-v, plinq

I have a PLINQ query as such...

```
batch
.AsParallel()
.WithExecutionMode(ParallelExecutionMode.ForceParallelism)
.WithCancellation(cancellationToken);
.Select(i => new { instruction = i, accountKey = new AccountKey(i.x, i.y, i.z) })
.GroupBy(x => x.accountKey)
.ForAll(grouping =>
{
    foreach (var instructionBatch in grouping.OrderBy(i => i.instruction.FileRow).Select(i => i.instruction))
    {
        // High CPU method.
    }
});
```

In a batch, there can be 10,000 records. These make calls to the High CPU method which in turn is making calls out to web-services and saving info to databases.

On my physical 64bit pc i7-4770 CPU @ 3.40 GHz 16.0GB ram. The service where this code is run from fires up around 32 threads and sits around 150,000 - 200,000 KB memory usage.

On a Hyper-V test environment which is a 64 bit virtual machine E5-2630 v3 @2.40GHz it generates over 200 threads and memory hits nearly the 2gb limit.

Is there any reason why it is firing up so many threads and why memory is not being released on the virtual machine?

Do I need to use WithDegreeOfParallelism. If this process might be called simultaneously with 4 different batches (1 x 1 record, 1 x 100 records, 1 x 1000 and 1 x 10,000 for example) does this mean that when if I specify a WithDegreeOfParallelism the 4 batches will each fire with that number of threads, even the batch of 1 record?

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end whist running performance monitor I noticed that in the virtualized environment, the perf counter # of Exceps Thrown / Sec was showing a very high number. I followed http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2011/06/23/how-to-figure-out-what-exception-is-causing-a-high-number-in-of -exceps-thrown-sec-using-procdump-and-windbg.aspx and identified that an unhandled exception was being thrown whilst trying to connect to a mysql db. This was due to a firewall rule not being in place.

With regards to the parallelism. A second fire and forget task further down the High CPU method was being started to generate letters. This however did not 
any exception/logging handling around it. This was where the error was being thrown. To overcome this I wrapped the await Task.Run in a try catch.

Answer (score 1):

The TPL `Parallel` and PLINQ facilities are not good at handling IO. They tend to chose bad thread counts. The thread count employed by these methods is heuristically driven. I believe it is the thread-pool that contains this heuristic.

When IO is in play I highly recommend using `WithDegreeOfParallelism`. You can use `Environment.ProcessorCount`. If there is IO involved you probably want to slightly over-subscribe and add a constant amount of threads.

In PLINQ `WithDegreeOfParallelism` is an absolute amount. No more, no less. So yes, 4 concurrent queries result in 4 times the number of threads. I believe this problem does not happen with the built-in automatic thread count heuristic.

Consider using a fixed concurrency `TaskScheduler` for all concurrent queries.

Here's an experiment: Run that loop with a `Thread.Sleep(1000000)`. You'll find tons of threads. Probably, one every 500ms. This is the thread-pools way of injecting threads when it thinks more are needed to avoid deadlocks and increase utilization. Totally inappropriate for IO.

Comment: Thanks for this @usr. If i use TPL parallel with MaxDegreeOfParallelism. it seems to limit the threads. However the other issue that i still see is whereby the memory constanly creeps up on the Hyper-V machine until it nears the 2GB limit. On the physical machine. You can see the memory being used and released around the 180,000 KB mark. Are you aware if this is an environment issue or is it something that i need to code for in the application?

Comment: I doubt it's an environment issue. Maybe different thread count or other IO latency profile. There was/is a bug with PLINQ in that it does not always release object references in a timely manner. That can keep garbage alive. Consider pushing wrapper objects through PLINQ that you manually clear. For example if you push a List<int> call Clear on that list when you are done. The now almost empty list might stay around but not the original big list.